# Avoid twitter profile names (@Profile) with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to analyze tweets but want to avoid the profile users names that are followed by an @ (@Profile_name) using regex!

I've tried:

```
re.findall(r'(?!@[\w+]*)(\w+)', "I want to take everything but @this, but I cannot find a way"))
```

and it gives me:

```
>>>> [['I', 'want', 'to', 'take', 'everything', 'but', 'this', 'but', 'I', 'cannot', 'find', 'a', 'way']]
```

I don't want the "this" :/
I'm quite new in regex, but I really cannot solve this one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

> `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`
>
> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl. If the pattern isn’t found, string is returned unchanged. repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, `\n` is converted to a single newline character, `\r` is converted to a carriage return, and so forth. Unknown escapes such as `\j` are left alone. Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(@\w+)', "", "I want to take everything but @this, but I cannot find a way")
'I want to take everything but , but I cannot find a way'
```